# Double IPv6 Static Addresses, is it possible?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, linux-networking, ipv6

I have two ISP, and I want to have two static IPv6 [::200].

It happens to work only one of them, if ISP 1 has the static one IPS 2 doesn't have static and uses 4 radom block ==> [:abcd:1111:3333:222]

this is my config:

I use debian, btw.

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eno1
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    address 192.0.2.200
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.0.2.1

iface eno1 inet6 static
    address 2001:db8:aaaa:1111::200
    netmask 64

allow-hotplug enp4s0
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
    address 198.51.100.200
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 198.51.100.1


iface enp4s0 inet6 static
    address 2001:db8:bbbb:2222::200
    netmask 64
```

IPv4 is working like a charm, not problem at all with it.
Just to be clear, if eno1 is using static IPv6 enp4s0 doesn't get it as static (seems to be dhcp -- and it works, it's reachable by internet users).

---

update:
For some reason, using Ubuntu 22.04 netplan's configuration works.
Netplan uses my static addresses and add two more that seems comming from router dhcp server. I don't know how and and where it should be setup on debian. But for those who wants to use it, ubuntu ftw.

Comment: It may be that the ISP router RAs for enp4s0 prevent static address assignment.

Comment: @RonMaupin, if I deactivate the eno1 interface, enp4s0 assigns its IPv6 as static...

Comment: Silly question: is the obfuscated `xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::` twice the same in both places? If they are not at least replace the second with `yyyy:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy::`. If they are the same, that's probably the issue. When you obfuscate, please use documentation addresses instead. For IPv6 that's any subnet within the 2001:DB8::/32 net. Also, as a remark, I doubt the IPv4 setup can work like a charm when defining twice a default route (the two gateway entries) and with nothing telling they'll have a different metric nor any policy-based routing hint anywhere.

Comment: No, they are diff. Again, if I stop using one as static, the othe IP gets the static address.

Comment: I modified that addressing to follow the IANA Special Use addressing for example addressing. IANA sets aside three IPv4 address ranges (`192.0.2.0/24`, `198.51.100.0/24`, and `203.0.113.0/24`) and one IPv6 address range (`2001,db8::/32`) for you to use as example addresses. You should use those ranges, and anyone can see that they are examples. Using Private address ranges for WAN addresses seems to mean you are really trying to do that.

Comment: If the devices are using the same subnet, in my humble opinion, you will need to divide the IPv6 into smaller pieces. However, if they are completely different, then using a /64 would be sufficient. Nevertheless, I would kindly request an update on the question to provide us with more accurate information.